# Automate windows login process using python

Tags: python, pywinauto, pyautogui

How can we automate a windows logon process using python script when the machine is been deployed over V Sphere server.
I have tried winnium,Pywinauto and even pyvmomi libraries but unable to locate the element inside the child window of Pysphere.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you trying to automate Windows login process from the same machine you are logging into?

Comment: No trying to automate login process of another machine which is deployed in a virtual box environment.

Comment: Maybe auto logon is more appropriate solution? Along with starting VNC server and running automation script on the target machine.